# Why are member functions passed differently than local functions to a std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, stdthread

I'm trying to understand how `std::thread` is used.

The header looks as follows:

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

- How does one identify whether `f` is a universal ref or rvalue? From what I found online:

> "If T is getting deduced and variable / parameter type is unqualified T&& , then only it’s a Universal Reference."

what does `unqualified T&&` refer to? `auto` or `template`?

- If I have a function `foo`, I could call use it like `std::thread(foo)`. Does that mean `foo` is being used as an lvalue reference because it doesn't qualify for rvalue reference?
- Why does the way a function is passed differ from in the case of member functions? if `foo` was a part of the class, you won't be able to use it like `std::thread(obj.foo)` - instead `std::thread(&Class::foo, &obj)` works. What's the logical reasoning behind it?
- How does one pass a local variable/vector to a thread? I tried the following but in the function itself, I can't access any vector elements even though `vector.size()` does output correctly.

```
void Class::foo(vector<int>v)
{
   std::cout<<v[0]; // prints nothing
}

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int>v = {12,3};

    Class obj;

    std::thread t1(&Class::foo, &obj, v);

    t1.join();

}
```

Comment: You need to show the *entire* program. If it is too large make a smaller version of it to show. If I had to bet, you are exiting your function and destroying your local variables and then using their dead zombie corpses in your thread. Don't do that.

Comment: Also, member function pointers are different because they are always *two* pointers. A pointer to the function and a pointer to the object to call that function with.

Answer (score 1):

> what does unqualified `T&&` refer to?

It refers to the function parameter of the function template. `f` and `args...` are the parameters. They satifsy the described requirment of being forwarding references (as long as the template type argument isn't passed explicitly inn which case the type would not be deduced from the function argument).

> Why does the way a function is passed differ from in the case of member functions?

Because non static member functions have an implicit instance parameter, and because they don't implicitly decay to pointer to member function.

> How does one pass a local variable/vector to a thread?

Depends on context. Copying is usually simplest.

Comment: 1) examples of no explicit argument passing include `auto` and `template` since the type is deduced in runtime? 2) by implicit instance matter you mean `this` pointer? 3) do you see what's wrong with my code?

Comment: @Jazzy 1) It applies to function templates. `auto&&` may be used as parameter of a function template in which case it is a forwarding reference 2) Yes. 3) No. https://godbolt.org/z/6Pea47

Comment: Fair. I was using `unsigned` type (my bad) and realized you have to specify `(unsigned)` in streams. Understood the additional `this` pointer, but why is the "address"(?) of the member function being passed as a first argument, and the second is being the reference of the object? Still unclear about the way things are passed in case of member functions